# Swift generic sequence observable ambiguity

Tags: swift, generics, rx-swift

I've got following code

```
protocol NamedOption {
    var optionTitle: String { get }
}

struct DebugOption: NamedOption {
    let optionTitle: String
    let debugViewControllerType = UIViewController.self
}


func testFunk<T: Sequence>(d: Observable<T>) where T.Element == NamedOption {

}

func bindFullResultsRx() {
    let dd: Observable<[DebugOption]> = self.dataModel.debugOptions // this is defined and properly assigned earlier
    testFunk(d: dd)
}
```

and at the line where I call `testFunk` Xcode gives me following error:

> Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context

I have no idea why this is happening :( So far I was able to make it working by changing constraints on `testFunk` into this:

```
func funk<T: NamedOption>(d: Observable<[T]>) {

}
```

which seems to me more restrictive then version at the top. Does any one knows how to make it working with `T: Sequence` ?

Xcode version is 9.4, Swift version is 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and help from work colleagues I was able to make it working by simply changing `==` into `:` so it looks like this

```
func testFunk<T: Sequence>(d: Observable<T>) where T.Element: NamedOption {

}
```

It's just a matter of swift syntax
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/GenericParametersAndArguments.html

> conformance-requirement → type-identifier : protocol-composition-type

Answer (score 0):

OO and generics don't play too well together. In order to do what you want, you have to manually cast up as in:

```
testFunk(d: dd.map { $0.map { $0 as NamedOption } })
```